# Get Filename from random picturebox

Tags: vb.net

i have picturebox that display image random from directory i want to get name of every image from picturebox to label

```
 Dim rnd As New Random
    Dim alljpgs() As String = IO.Directory.GetFiles("C:\Users\" + Environment.UserName.ToString + "\AppData\SystemInfo\Images", "*.jpg", IO.SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly)
    Dim jpg As New Bitmap(alljpgs(rnd.Next(0, alljpgs.Count - 1)))
    PictureBox14.Image = jpg

    ' Label24.Text = (IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(jpg.ToString))
    Dim x As String = Path.GetFileName(PictureBox14.ImageLocation)
    Label24.Text = x
```

but it's not working how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Store the index of the randomly selected image in a variable `i`. Then use it to set the contents of the `PictureBox` and `Label`.

```
Dim rnd As New Random
Dim alljpgs() As String = IO.Directory.GetFiles("C:\Users\" + Environment.UserName.ToString + "\AppData\SystemInfo\Images", "*.jpg", IO.SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly)
Dim i as Integer = rnd.Next(0, alljpgs.Count - 1)
Dim jpg As New Bitmap(alljpgs(i))
PictureBox14.Image = jpg
Label24.Text = IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(alljpgs(i))
```